# How can I make the Firefox button menu instead of the menu toolbar in Firefox V29.0

Tags: firefox

After update to Firefox v29.0, I found the **Firefox button menu** cannot be found anymore.

I followed the steps from [Firefox official instruction](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/display-firefox-button-menu-instead-menu-toolbar), but the **Firefox button menu** still cannot be displayed.

The screenshot has been attached:
[image: firefox_menu_bar]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button has been replaced by the hamburger button (a button with three horizontal lines) on the right-hand side of your toolbar.

Comment: But... this "hamburger button" will be hidden after set `set gui=nonavigation` in vimperatorrc

Comment: Okay, I know why it changes to "hamburger" button, it (might) comes from twitter design: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/IMG_1990.jpg | http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/08/the-semantic-responsive-design-navicon/

Answer (score 0):

By using [Firefox ESR version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/): [v24.0](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest-24.0esr/) (This is [ftp](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/)) can display the button menu.

About the [Firefox ESR lifr cycle](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/):
[image: esr]